# How to get visitor data & store detail in database in magento2

Tags: magento2, database, frontend

I want to get visitor data when any visitor visit magento website. In visitor detail, I want to get IP address, browser name , Operating System Name , First Visit Time, & Last Visit time. How is it possible? This Feature must working on all page of magento website.

Please Help Me.

Thanks in advance. :-)

Comment: This works. Check `customer_visitor` table in admin panel. But it doesnt have all the data you want. That you need to code differently.

Comment: Try this method `getVisitorData()` to get Data from session object. Check what you can get. If not... try to get data from request header like `http_user_agent` to get the browser, `remote_addr` to get the IP address etc etc.

Comment: `Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor` is the class where Magento is setting visitors information by using `setVisitorData` inside `initByRequest()` function.

Comment: Please put code here if you have.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So try this. But this wont save your data in `customer_visitor` table at least not the fields i added.

```
public function initByRequest($observer) //Magento\Customer\Model\Visitor - PATH
    {
        if ($this->skipRequestLogging || $this->isModuleIgnored($observer)) {
            return $this;
        }
        if ($this->session->getVisitorData()) {
            $this->setData($this->session->getVisitorData());
        }

        $this->setLastVisitAt((new \DateTime())->format(\Magento\Framework\Stdlib\DateTime::DATETIME_PHP_FORMAT));
        $this->setHttpUserAgent($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']); // setting user browser to object
        $this->setUserRemoteAddr($_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']); //setting user ip to object

        if (!$this->getId()) {
            $this->setSessionId($this->session->getSessionId());
            $this->save();
            $this->_eventManager->dispatch('visitor_init', ['visitor' => $this]);
            $this->session->setVisitorData($this->getData());
        }
        return $this;
    }
```

Now remove your cookies from browser and try to get the value like this

```
$this->session->getVisitorData(); // Or where you want to get the data by initializing session object and get it.
```

> Now you will get something like this Array ( [last_visit_at] =>
>   2017-04-06 07:35:44 [http_user_agent] => Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1;
>   WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/57.0.2987.133
>   Safari/537.36 [user_remote_addr] => 127.0.0.1 [session_id] =>
>   9c2uc36v01is5mn30q890o1ih2 [visitor_id] => 22 )